# Sql Azure: The session limit for the database is 8000 and has been reached

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I am getting following exception in SQL Azure, my SQL Server database is a web version, and I am getting this error in SQL Server Management Studio (when connecting). Also this is happening when connecting through my web application interface.

> Resource ID : 2. The session limit for the database is 8000 and has been reached. See 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267637' for assistance.
>   Login failed for user '--'.
>   This session has been assigned a tracing ID of 'f47cc110-a9ef-439b-b575-4240aba929eb'.  Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.

This seems to be like Windows Azure limitation, but if anyone came across such situation please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What edition of Azure database you are using Web / Business? Also can you check what is being queued up in `dm_exec_requests` ? Check out [Resource Governance in Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn338078.aspx)

Comment: Most probably your app has a connection [leak](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2009/10/13/connection-leak-its-symptoms-and-troubleshooting.aspx). [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2011/05/06/how-to-create-a-connection-leak-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx)'s an example about how to avoid them.

Comment: I am using Business Edition for Sql Azure,

select * from sys.dm_exec_requests

its returning only one record and showing no held problem.

This is probably due to limitation of Sql Azure,
Did someone ever came across such problem?